# Slick Grid not refreshing with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have this sclick grid which is loaded with the page load. Now i want that the data on the slick grid to be replaced by the new data on the click of a checkbox(i am using an ajax call to get the new data) and the check box should retain its value. I can see that although the server gives the new data the slick grid doesnt refreshes and the checkbox doesnt retains the state(i.e checked) on the page load.

**Jsp:**

```
 <c:if test="${info == null or empty info}">
                    <div id="result" class="ui-widget" style="float:center">
                    <strong>No results found !</strong>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
```

**Slick grid:**

```
  var dataView;
      var grid;
      var data = [];
      var options = {
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        showHeaderRow: true,
        headerRowHeight: 40,
        explicitInitialization: true,
        enableColumnReorder: false,
        multiColumnSort: true,
        defaultSortAsc:false,

      };
      var columns = [];
      var columnFilters = {};
      {  
      ....
      ...

      }


          $(function () {

               var holder=new Array();
                var i=0;
                 var d = (data[i] = {});
                 <c:forEach var="message" items="${info}" >
                 holder[i]={
                            id: i,
                            remove: '<c:out value="${message.id}"/>' ,
                            name: '<c:out value="${message.name}"/>',
                            status: '<c:out value="${message.status}"/>'
                            }
                      i++; 
                  </c:forEach>

            dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
            grid = new Slick.Grid("#rulesGrid", dataView, columns, options);
            var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#rulesPager"));

            grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args){
            dataView.fastSort(args.sortCol.field, args.sortAsc);
            grid.render();
            });


            dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
              grid.updateRowCount();
              grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);//new change
              grid.render();
            });



            grid.init();
            dataView.beginUpdate();
            dataView.setItems(holder);
            dataView.setFilter(filter);
            dataView.endUpdate();
            dataView.refresh();
            grid.invalidate();
            grid.updateRowCount();
            grid.render();
          });
```

**Ajax call:**

```
function PopulateGrids(){
    var showInactive,showSubmitted;
    if($("#showInactive").is(':checked')){
        showInactive=true;
    }
    else if($("#showSubmitted").is(':checked')){
        showSubmitted=true;
    }
    else if($("#showSubmitted").is(':checked') && $("#showInactive").is(':checked'))
        {
        showInactive=true;
        showSubmitted=true;
        }


    jQuery.ajax( {
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        url : "/application/createNewResult/details?showInactive="+encodeURI(showInactive)+"&showSubmitted="+encodeURI(showSubmitted) ,
        type : 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function() {
            alert("showInactive: "+showInactive+" show submitted: "+showSubmitted);
            console.log("info:",'<c:out value="${info}"/>');
            if(showInactive)
                $("#showInactive").prop('checked', true);
            else if(showSubmitted )
                $("#showSubmitted").prop('checked', true);          
        },
        complete : function(request, status) {
            if (status == undefined || status == "error" || status == "parsererror") {
                alert('error in searching Invalid or submitted records: '+status);
                window.location.href="/application/createNewResult/";
            } else if (status != 'success'){
                alert('error in searching Invalid or submitted records: '+status);

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax call, your success callback function can contain a 'result' parameter, like:

```
success: function(result) {...
```

From the server, you'll define what data should come back in that 'result' parameter (the new data for your grid), and using javascript, you can replace the original data with the new data.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this part "replace the original data with the new data."

Comment: I was just referring back to your original question.  You said that you wanted the data in your grid to be replaced when the user clicked on a checkbox. So presumably, you capture the checkbox 'click' event and call your ajax function.  In the 'success' portion of your ajax call, you can include a parameter that contains the server's response to your ajax call.  I called it 'result', sometimes people call it 'data', but you can call it whatever you want.  This page has an example of what I'm talking about: http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

Comment: To clarify further, the new data I'm referring to is what you get from your 'createNewResult' function.

Answer (score 0):

i found another way of doing that by getting all the data from the server and showing the new data(intended data) on the event on the checkbox. This method is faster than maxing an ajax call and it also retains the state of the checkbox(checked).This is how i did it:

```
   $("#showInactive").change(function(e,args) {

            if(this.checked) {

                         var holder=new Array();
                            var i=0;
                             var d = (data[i] = {});
                             <c:forEach var="message" items="${info}">
                                 holder[i]={
                                        id: i,
                                        remove: '<c:out value="${message.Id}"/>' ,
                                        rule: '<c:out value="${message.Name}"/>',
                                        status: '<c:out value="${message.status}"/>'
                                        }
                                  i++; 
                              </c:forEach>
                             grid.init();
                                dataView.beginUpdate();
                                dataView.setItems(holder);
                                dataView.endUpdate();
                                dataView.refresh();
                                grid.invalidate();
                                grid.updateRowCount();
                                grid.render();
                             grid.render();
                    });
```